# How to add new row in the table on click a button in angular 7

Tags: html, angular

I have a table contains several rows and an add button with each row.When I click add button a new row should be created just below that row similar to that row.Here is the code below

### app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  ngOnInit() {

  }
  groups=[
     {
       "name": "pencils",
       "items": "red pencil"
     },
     {
       "name": "rubbers",
       "items": "big rubber"
     },
  ];
  //console.log(this.groups);
}
```

### app.component.html

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>Basic Table</h2>
  <p>The .table class adds basic styling (light padding and only horizontal dividers) to a table:</p>            
  <table class="table border">

    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let row of groups">
       <td> {{row.name}} </td>
       <td> {{row.items}} </td>
       <td> <button>Add</button> </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I click add button a new row should be created just below that
>   row similar to that row.

Pass the current index where the button is clicked and insert an item at that index.

**HTML:**

```
 <tr *ngFor="let row of groups; let i = index">
     <td> {{row.name}} </td>
     <td> {{row.items}} </td>
     <td> <button (click)="addItem(i)">Add</button> </td>
 </tr>
```

**Component:**

We are using JavaScript's [splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method to insert an item at that specific index.

```
addItem(index) {
  var currentElement = this.groups[index];  
  this.groups.splice(index, 0, currentElement);
}
```

Live demo on StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1pd6yx

Answer (score 2):

Just add it to the array and the view will update.

```
<td> <button (click)="addItem()">Add</button> </td>
```

```
public addItem(): void {
 this.groups.push({name: 'foo', items: 'bar});
}
```

Comment: @nullptr.t - Your code just inserts an item at the end which isn't what OP asked for. Check out my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57733059/2924577.

Answer (score 0):

a. Add click handler to the button

```
<button (click)="addRow(row)">Add</button>
```

b. Add method to the component

```
addRow(row: {name: string; items: string;}): void {
    this.groups.push(row);
 },
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer here I need to get the same data as clicked row on my new row,It should not come hardcoded and it should add just below that row itself,it should not add at totally bottom

Comment: @UIAPPDEVELOPER I updated my answer but actually you should read the angular documentation, there they explain everything in detail.